# disable selection background color in css

Tags: html, css

[image]

i have some divs, when i double click on the any of the div there is blue background selection
are shown, i donot want this blue selection background , this looks weired.. any help to remove this seletion background...
in the image there is grey background

Comment: Where is your code, have you missed it?

Comment: You'll kind of ruin the user's expected behavior if you do this. If they want to select something, they wouldn't know if it worked properly.

Comment: simply double click on my question's any word.. you can see the selection blue background...

Comment: You want different color for selection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS rule to disable text selection highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/Jk6XF/

we make use of the property `user-select: none;`

if you want this to be cross browser, make sure you include all the vendor prefixes

Although using this property should be avoided. But if this makes you happy, go ahead ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [**`user-select`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

```
(-prefix-)user-select: none;
```

The text of the element and sub-elements will not be able to be selected.

Comment: this provided to the specific div which shows the blue background

Comment: @Jat.net this is disable the double click in the div so there will be no blue color.  Incas if you want to change the color then you can use `(-webkit-)-tap-highlight-color` works only in chrome and safari